# Get error when i open the android folder in flutter project red lines in build.gradle any idea

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am trying to use fire-base when i am make a new project in flutter every things is fine but when i open the android folder in my project i get an error at this line of android>app>build.gradle any idea please

throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a successful installation of:

- Android Studio
- Flutter SDK (you can check if you run `flutter doctor` in your terminal
- You have defined the Flutter sdk on your `$PATH` (Flutter doctor should tell you)

I also found it difficult to open the `Android` folder in Android Studio.
What worked for me however was:

## Remove the .idea/ folder for your project

I'm not sure if this step is necessary, but I always do it when I have conflicts opening project in either Android Studio or Intellij.
This is basically where it keeps its configuration.
[image]

## Open up Android Studio

Click on *Open an existing Android Studio project*
[image]

## Select the `android` folder from your project

[image]

Hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

the following steps might help you.

open your android project in flutter and select in this window, it won't show any error. Then re-open your flutter project and select in this window, you will find everything is OK.